# How to run .exe without admin rights at school

Tags: installation, admin, uac, rights

I am trying to play some online games on the school computers.

Although everytime i try to run exes of setups such as Hearthstone-Setup-enUS.exe i get the User Account Control blocking me from installing applications.

I undersrand that installing pirated software on the school computers is ilegal but I just want to play free online games.

Is there a way to bypass the UAC?
School's Computer run Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, no. Whenever a UAC prompt is there you can't run it without administrator rights. 
You **can** however try installing it into a flash drive (at home) and if you are lucky enough the game itself might run off of that. UAC blocks most installers, but it doesn't touch quite a lot of actual applications.

HOWEVER, schools tend to have common online game ports blocked, and there's a good chance that even if your game launches it wont connect.

Answer (score 1):

Just install the game on any external storage such as USB and play from it .

Comment: installing on a flash drive wont run. UAC blocks ALL ports to unknown exe sources